# Check for convergence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{\Gamma \left ( n+\frac{1}{4} \right )}{\Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{4}\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> I need to check the convergence of the series
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot \cdots\cdot (4n-3)}{n!}$$

I was able to simplify the numbers and get this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{\Gamma \left ( n+\frac{1}{4} \right )}{\Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )}$$

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to check the new series for convergence at once? If so, what signs should be used?
2. Is there any way to simplify the expression $\frac{\Gamma \left ( n+\frac{1}{4} \right )}{\Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )}$ to work further?

Comment: Is it $4n-3$ or $4n-1$?

Comment: It reads $4n-3$

Comment: By ratio test
$$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot \ldots\cdot (4(n+1)-3)}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot \ldots\cdot (4n-3)}=\frac{(4n+1)(4n-1)}{n+1} $$

Comment: Notice that, replacing $4$ by $x$, it is the binomial expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1-x}}-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divergence is obvious because $$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots (4n-3)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n}$$

tends to infinity.

To see that this happens just observe that the numerator has $2n-1$ terms and the first $n$ of them are term by term greater than the ones in the denominator:

$$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots (4n-3)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n} = \frac{1}{1}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{5}{3}\cdots \frac{2n-1}{n}\cdot(2n+1)\cdot(2n+3)\cdots(4n-3)$$ $$ > (2n+1)\cdot(2n+3)\cdots(4n-3)$$

Answer (score 1):

As already noticed, by ratio test on the original expression we obtain

$$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot \ldots\cdot (4(n+1)-3)}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot \ldots\cdot (4n-3)}=\frac{(4n+1)(4n-1)}{n+1} \to \infty$$

and the series diverges.

As an alternative expression we can also use the following

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4(4n-3)!}{4^nn!(2n-2)!}$$